# How can I pass a variable into a postdelayed runnable?

Tags: java, runnable, postdelayed

I have created two classes implemented from runnable().  I then call them several times, with varying delay.  The problem is, when I run the runnable later, it needs to know the value of a variable back when the postdelay was called, not when it's actually run.

I think what I now need to do is pass the variable into the runnable instance when I call the post delay.  But for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it.  Here is the source code for reference:

```
public void PlaySequence() throws InterruptedException{

for(int i = 0;i<level;i++){
    mHandler.postDelayed(mToggleButtonOn, (i+1)*playbackOffTime);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mToggleButtonOff, (i+1)*playbackOnTime);           
    currentProgIteration++;
}        
currentProgIteration=0;     
}

private Runnable mToggleButtonOn = new Runnable() {

public void run() {
    try {
            if(Sequence[currentProgIteration]==0){
                ImageCard[0].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yellow));
            }
            else if(Sequence[currentProgIteration]==1){
                ImageCard[1].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue));
            }
            else if(Sequence[currentProgIteration]==2){
                ImageCard[2].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red));
            }
            else if(Sequence[currentProgIteration]==3){
                ImageCard[3].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green));
            }                   
        }
     catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
};

private Runnable mToggleButtonOff = new Runnable() {

public void run() {
    Log.d("Info", "running Off currentProgIteration: "+currentProgIteration);

    try {
            if(Sequence[currentProgIteration]==0){
                ImageCard[0].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.darkyellow));
            }
            else if(Sequence[currentProgIteration]==1){
                ImageCard[1].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.darkblue));
            }
            else if(Sequence[currentProgIteration]==2){
                ImageCard[2].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.darkred));
            }
            else if(Sequence[currentProgIteration]==3){
                ImageCard[3].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.darkgreen));
            }                   
        }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
};
```

The runnables are using global variable currentProgIteration, but by the time they run after the delay, that variable has been set back to 0.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach may be to use an anonymous Runnable.

```
final int delay = (i+1)*playbackOffTime;
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   final Color[] colours = { R.drawable.yellow, R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.red, R.drawable.green } ;
   public void run() {
        try {
           // can use "delay" here
           int seq = Sequence[currentProgIteration];
           ImageCard[seq].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(colours[seq]));
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to use this and still have the option to call 'removeCallbacks(...)' to cancel the anonymous Runnable? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: @CoryTrese Sure if mHandler supports that. If you use ExecutorService, it returns a Future which can be cancel()led.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter said, you can use anonymous `Runnable`

to make  removeCallbacks(...) possible you could remove runnables with token:

create top level token to distinct Runnables posted onto MessageQueue, like

`val animToken = Any()`

in order to track your runnable, use following extension:

```
fun Handler.postDelayedWithToken(token: Any, delayInMillis: Long, runnable: Runnable) {
    postAtTime(runnable, token, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + delayInMillis)
}
```

sample use:
`handler.postDelayedWithToken(animToken, 3000L, { hideSomething() })`

in order to dispose (e.g: before onPause / onStop / onDestroyView):

`handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(animToken)`